# Stacking divs next to each other/horizontally

Tags: css, html, position

My divs do not stack up next to each other

What do I do?
One div comes below the other.

I tried all types of positioning and even relative but it doesn't work.

```
<head>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
   <meta name="author" content="Chaitanya Gupta">

<meta name="keywords" content="Fashion, Learning, Resources ">
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy&effect=3d-float' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script&effect=3d-float' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">
   <title>FLR</title>
```

CSS

```
 <style type="text/css">
        hr
        {
        color:white;
        border-width: 2px;
        border:medium silver dashed;
        }

        a:link,a:visited
        {
        display:block;
        color:white;
        }

        a:hover,a:active
        {
        background-color:#7C868E;
        text-decoration: underline;
        border-radius:8px
        }

        a
        {
        font-family: "Century Gothic";
        font-variant:small-caps;
        font-size: 20px;
        }

        #emboss 
        {
        border-right: 4px solid #2b2b2b;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #2b2b2b;
        }

        #subTopic
        {
        font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
        font-size:60px;
        font-weight:lighter;;
        font-variant:small-caps;
        }

        #content
        {
        color:white;
        font-family: 'Bad Script', cursive;
        font-size:20px;
        }

        div.menu
        {
        background-color:#4A5662; 
        float:left; 
        width:150px; 
        height:210px; 
        border-radius:8px; 
        margin-top:20px; 
        margin-left:5px; 
        text-align:center; 
        padding-top:10px; 
        padding-bottom:10px
        }

        div.content
        {

        float:right;



        }


           </style>

    <script>

    </script>
</head>
```

HTML

```
<body background="denim.jpg">


   <img src="fas.jpg" style="float:right; height:80px; width:200px;">
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <hr>

   <div id="emboss" class="menu" >

   <a href="" onclick="displayAbout()">About</a></span>
   <br>
   <a href="" >Careers</a>
   <br>
   <a href="">Clients</a>
   <br>
   <a href="">Blogs</a>
   <br>
   <a href="">Contact Us</a>
   </div>

   <div class="content" id="display">
   <h1 id="subTopic" class="font-effect-3d-float">About</h1>

   <p id="content">FASHION LEARNING RESOURCES (FLR) is a Gurgaon, 
   India based small company pioneering Fashion Education & 
   Training Technology(FETT) products, services, consulting and 
   delivery services in FETT for the fashion institutes, 
   industry bodies and government. FLR also offers E learning 
   & multimedia content in Fashion / apparel Domain. 
   FLR is started by founding alumni batch of NIFT.</p>
   </div>

   <!--<hr style="position:absolute; bottom:30px; width: 1200px">
   <code style="color:white; position:absolute; bottom:10px">Copyright &copy 2013 Fashion Learning Resources. All rights reserved.</code>
-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please put it in the jfiddle

Comment: just set width to your content class

Comment: I agree with @Sharky, you should have a width set.  This is part of the W3C standard and you'll see weirdness if you don't do it.  Resources for you: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: So much `<br />`.  Ever heard of margins/padding or lists?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to html and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
div.content
{
   margin:0 0 0 160px;
}
```

It may also be useful to wrap a div around menu and content with a spacific width and then make sure menu and content added together with margins and padding are that width.

```
div.wrap { width 800px}
div.content {width:640px}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the display  property in your div, and all divs with this will stack horizontally.

> display: inline-block

Comment: i know it is an answer. but this trivial thing could go as a comment :(

Comment: How do you make a comment in the main post?

Comment: @madhairsilence Sometimes trivial things *are*  the answer.

Comment: lolz.. Funny that , stack overflow description insists " Question needs to have some research". Up to that, this question should have been closed by this time!! after providing the solution

Answer (score 1):

Use display:inline-block within the CSS definition, that should stack them horizontally for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 div.content
    {
    width:calc(100% - 160px);
    float:right;



    }
```

This should work

This will keep the div with class menu to the left and the content div in the right

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulmalik/bVZ23/)

```
 div.menu
    {
    background-color:#4A5662; 

    height:210px; 
    border-radius:8px; 
    margin-top:20px; 
    margin-left:5px; 
    text-align:center; 
    padding-top:10px; 
    padding-bottom:10px
    }
div.menu a{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and remove `<br/>` tag after every anchor

```
<div id="emboss" class="menu" >

   <a href="" onclick="displayAbout()">About</a></span>
   <a href="" >Careers</a>
   <a href="">Clients</a>
   <a href="">Blogs</a>
   <a href="">Contact Us</a>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy just do

```
div.content
    {
    /*float:right;*/
    }
```

if you want to make it `float:right` just give it width, check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GafgA/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove float: right and add a margin - http://jsfiddle.net/xEGRg/

```
div.content {
  margin-left: 230px;
}
```